# Java - Quick way to find the four "extreme corners" in a set of points?

Tags: java, optimization, coordinates

Assuming we're given an x and y bound (lets call the bounds A and B) for a set of random coordinates, for example x <= 10, y <= 10. What is the fastest way to find the four points closest to (0,0), (A,0), (A,B), (0,B)? The points may be ordered from least to greatest if that is faster. This is what I have currently, but I feel like this can be sped up:

```
 private void quadrilateral(){
    NW = null;
    NE = null;
    SE = null;
    SW = null;
    Point NWbound = new Point(0,B);
    Point NEbound = new Point(A,B);
    Point SEbound = new Point(A, 0);
    Point SWbound = new Point(0,0);
    for (Point p : points){
        if (NW == null || p.distance(NWbound) < NW.distance(NWbound)){
            NW = p;
        }
        if (NE == null || p.distance(NEbound) < NE.distance(NEbound)){
            NE = p;
        }
        if (SE == null || p.distance(SEbound) < SE.distance(SEbound)){
            SE = p;
        }
        if (SW == null || p.distance(SWbound) < SW.distance(SWbound)){
            SW = p;
        }
    }
```

}

I haven't yet been able to utilize an ordered list, and I'm not even sure if ordering the list would help at all.

Comment: How do you plan to order two-dimensional points?

Comment: @AndyTurner Probably just by ordering the x values, and if x1==x2 then order it by y value. But I really have no idea if that helps.

Comment: Ordering implies sorting, implies `O(n log n)` time complexity. Just iterating the points, like you are now, if `O(n)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner That is true, but I wasn't sure if there is some "shortcut" by sorting the points.

Comment: If this code is working, it might be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The code might speed up if you were to calculate distance squared instead of distance (avoids a square root). But this wouldn't change the time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it faster, use p.distanceSq() instead of p.distance(). Also, save each of the four closest distance-squared values so you don't have to keep computing them again for each iteration.

Comment: Wow, I can' t believe I missed that second part. Silly mistake.

Comment: You can also avoid the null checks if you assign `NE = SE = NW = SW = points.get(0)`, and iterate over `points.subList(1, points.size())`.